# Is it possible to be notified when ntpd has updated system time?

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I have a Raspberry Pi. It has no RTC.

When it loses power, it has no idea how long it's been off until it checks the current time with NTP.

I installed ntpd on it, and am running it as a systemd service. That works fine.

I have software running on the Pi that does non-essential, time-based stuff. That means that if the current system time is accurate, it can do the task, but if the current system time may or may not be accurate, it can (and should) skip the task.

The way to know if the system clock is accurate, conceptually, seems simple - if the system has successfully used ntpd to update its time since it booted, the clock is accurate. Otherwise, assume the clock isn't accurate.

Is it possible to somehow get ntpd to tell me if it has successfully connected to the internet, retrieved the current time, and updated the system clock since last boot? I would rather not have my software try to parse ntpd's logs, if I can avoid it.

Comment: FreeBSD (and perhaps other BSDs) has an `rc.conf` feature `ntpdate_enable`. If set to `yes` then at boot time, FreeBSD will use `ntpdate` to do a one-time clock set.  Then, if one has also enabled the `ntpd` service, `ntpd` is launched, and keeps the clock syncronized from that moment on.  By enabling both of these features, one can ensure that the clock is set accurately once at start-up, and that `ntpd` is launched to keep the clock in sync thereafter.  Your OS may have a similar feature.

Comment: if you run auditd, all adjustments are logged in audit.log. Using ausearch to look for those adjustments might be a way to go...

Comment: @JimL. That assumes you have internet during boot, which isn't always the case. I have software that needs to start at boot. It can't sit around waiting for internet to be available at boot, for NTP to run, and clocks to be accurate before it starts up. It just needs to know if the system time is accurate or not at a particular point in time

Comment: Adding a cron job to run `ntpdate` `@reboot` may be another alternative.

Comment: @JakubLucký auditd doesn't appear to come pre-installed on the Pi's OS. It seems a little overkill to install an entire auditing system just for this one small byproduct of it. At that point, it might be easier just to read ntp logs

Comment: @JimL. same problem. No guarantee the Pi will have internet `@reboot`

Comment: You don't mention what OS you're running, but again with the BSDs, the start-up logic is smart enough to know that networking has to be started before network time service can be used.  There's a definable heirarchy of service dependencies, so that you can tweak which services have to be established before other services can be started. I'm pretty sure systemd does some sort of similar ordering of service start-ups.

Comment: @JimL. It's just Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS. It's Debian based. The problem isn't NTP starting before the system has internet. The point is that my service MUST start, no matter if there's internet or not. It doesn't care if the NTP service is waiting for internet to start or not. It will always start at boot. But it needs to know if NTP had a chance to update system time or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see whether NTPD has worked - can't you enable logging for ntpd?

[Configuring ntpd log file](https://serverfault.com/questions/359835/where-are-the-ntpd-log-file-located-and-how-can-we-configure-the-ntpd-log-file) AND [RaspPI specific changes may be needed](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=11067)

And then run `ntpstat` (or whatever the equivalent on Debian is) or look at the logs to see what it's doing?

```
# ntpstat
synchronised to unspecified at stratum 6
   time correct to within 465816ms
   polling server every 1024 s
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't looked into parsing ntpd's logs yet, and it's definitely an option (I even mention it in my question at the end), but it's a last resort. Logs are meant to be read by people. Log output (wording) can be changed by the program (ntpd developers) at any point, without regard for what parsing scripts it might break, because it's not meant to be read by parsing tools. Parsing logs is inherently unreliable. `ntpstat` on the other hand appears to ask the ntp daemon directly, and seems like a good option.

Comment: Lots of other good ideas here https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-is-ntp-client-working/ - I've used ntpq before and it worked reasonably well..  Apparently the return code of ntpstat varies 0 is good, 1 is not synchronized, 2 is no idea..

Comment: Playing around with `ntpstat` for a few minutes, and reading through its documentation, it seems perfect. It has an exit code that returns 0 if clock is synchronized, and 1 if clock is not synchronized, which is literally meant to be used by scripts. Way more reliable than parsing logs. Perfect.